# Forms Authentication - Make an GET request secure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I'm new to Forms Authentication and am having difficulty with this problem:

I have a route set up like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
       "Account", // Route name
       "Account", // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "Account", action = "MyAccount", username = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

MyAccount action:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult MyAccount(MyAccountModel model, string username)
{
    // Do stuff with username and model
}
```

I noticed a security flaw in that the user could go:

```
../Account/MyAccount?username=test
```

And specify any username to receive info on that user. Is there anyway I can make this secure? I need to pass that username to this method to get stuff from my custom membership provider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is test whether the username is equal to that of the currently authenticated user.  Something like this:

```
[Authorize] 
public ActionResult MyAccount(MyAccountModel model, string username) 
{ 
    if (User.Identity.Name == username)
    {
        // Display account information
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Ok I didnt realise I could use User.Identity.Name. therefore I dont need to pass the username parameter and can remove that route! Thanks!